# "Go To Definition" does not work with constructors; is that a bug or is it by design?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

If I have this class:

```
Class Test
    Sub New()

    End Sub
End Class
```

and I have this instance:

```
 Dim x = New Test
```

When I right-click on `New` and select "Go To Definition", it doesn't do anything.  Is that a bug, or is it by design?  If it's the latter, what is the reason?

Comment: No, this is not opinion based.  It's either a bug, or it's by design, and that would be a fact not an opinion.

Comment: If you do go-to-definition on the `Test` part of `new Test` it should bring you to the constructor, just like for C#.

Comment: @Cameron -- No, it doesn't; it brings you to the class definition.  And in C#, using "go-to-definition" on `new` goes to the constructor.

Comment: Huh, I learnt something new about C#'s IntelliSense for `new`. I guess they didn't implement it for VB (if you look closely, there's tons of micro differences like this between the various language services). Too bad, this is a useful feature.

Comment: @Cameron -- So I guess that would be a vote for "bug" then, right?

Comment: Perhaps not the `new` part, but certainly when on the constructor name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not help you now, but Visual Studio 2015 (CTP6 as of this writing) works exactly as you would expect. If I have:

```
Public Class Test
    Sub New()
        '
    End Sub
End Class
```

And if I have the line:

```
    Dim x = New Test
```

If I click on `New` and Go To Definition, it takes me to the constructor. Thank you Roslyn!

Comment: That's great.  At least they're addressing it in a future version rather than carrying it along from version to version like I've seen with other bugs and deficiencies.  Thanks for this.

Answer (score -3):

Go To definition works for variables, data types and methods, not keywords.

[MSDN states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w13x3hh(v=vs.100).aspx):

"Use the Go to Definition command to navigate to the procedure for a method or a variable definition"

Comment: A constructor is a method.  Test it in C# ... works there just fine.

Comment: Could you bring up a link with a source for the claim that it isn't intended to work on constructors?

Comment: There is obviously a small difference in how this is implemented between c# and vb.net. If you try "Go to definition" on any c# keyword, you get an error message stating it can't be found. Try it in VB and it is just ignored. In VB, New is both an instantiating word as well as a keyword to define a constructor. The OPs exercise works on a class with or without a constructor, so it just simply navigates you to the class. in VB, just go to definition on the class itself, and not the New keyword, and the behavior will be the same.

Comment: @Jeremy "If you try "Go to definition" on any c# keyword, you get an error message stating it can't be found" -- Have you tried it on `new`?  It brings you to the constructor as desired.

Comment: @roryap yup, there is a small difference.

Comment: @roryap it works without a constructor as well. It just takes you to the class definition...

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan found your source.

Comment: @Jeremy -- "Could you bring up a link with a source for the claim that it isn't intended to work on constructors?" -- where does your source say that?

Comment: I modified my answer. It states the feature is intended for use on Variables and Methods. Nowhere does it mention keywords. The fact that it works on the C# keyword goes beyond this spec and should be considered a bonus, so it works as intended and documented in the VB editor.